# Links to URLs containing parentheses

Tags: support, status-completed, markdown, hyperlinks

How do I add a link to a URL containing parentheses `()` (or "round brackets" by heathens)?

For example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(VS.85).aspx

The parentheses around "VS.85" causes it to look like this:

#### Markdown:

`[IHtmlDocument2 reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(VS.85).aspx)`

#### Output renders as

[IHtmlDocument2 reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Can I further note that the preview is not consistent with the result at times. I detailed this in my "duplicate": [preview vs post linking difference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18323)

Comment: The team eventually decided that this was a bug, and has [fixed it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2323/please-improve-the-auto-linking-to-allow-square-and-round-brackets/2346#2346).

Comment: It is poor form to have parentheses in a URL, many RegExes will presume text with either parenthesis is not a URL.

Comment: @RVWard - Can you provide any real world examples?  RFC3986 states parenthesis are valid in general URI's and RFC1738 explicitly indicates parenthesis are valid in URL's.  And the link above is from Microsoft.com so I'm very doubtful that Microsoft would publish MSDN documentation links with invalid/unescaped URL's (regardless of what some might say about M$ & standards compliance ;) I'm not sure what standard you're using to classify it as "poor form."

Answer (score 141):

There are many ways to format URLs in Markdown. Parentheses work better with some methods than others.

```
1. Bare             - http://example.com/test(1).html
2. Bare, encoded    - http://example.com/test%281%29.html
3. Delimited        - <http://example.com/test(1).html>
4. Hyperlink        - with <a href="http://example.com/test(1).html">parens</a>
5. Markdown Link #1 - with [parens][1]
6. Markdown Link #1 - with [parens at end][2]
7. Markdown Link #2 - with [parens](http://example.com/test(1).html)
8. Markdown Link #2 - with [parens at end](http://example.com/test(1))
```

1. Bare             - http://example.com/test(1).html
2. Bare, encoded    - http://example.com/test%281%29.html
3. Delimited        - http://example.com/test(1).html
4. Hyperlink        - with [parens](http://example.com/test(1).html)
5. Markdown Link #1 - with [parens](http://example.com/test(1).html)
6. Markdown Link #1 - with [parens at end](http://example.com/test_(test))
7. Markdown Link #2 - with [parens](http://example.com/test(1).html)
8. Markdown Link #2 - with [parens at end](http://example.com/test(1))

Note also that parenthetical sections in [MSDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network) links are optional, so:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5471dc8s\(VS.80\).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5471dc8s%5C(VS.80%5C).aspx)

could be linked to, instead, as:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5471dc8s.aspx

See also [The Problem With URLs](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-urls/) for Jeff Atwood's blog post about coming up with a solution for Stack Overflow.

#### Other issues with URLs

Sometimes URLs can fail to link correctly because they contain disallowed characters. In these cases [encode the characters using the % notation](https://web.archive.org/web/20210627003309/http://i-technica.com/whitestuff/urlencodechart.html). Previously characters such as () [] ' and * were not allowed but the server-side Markdown renderer has been modified to accept them now. Currently the only (known) characters that aren't accepted are ones with accents, graves, diaeresis, etc. For example: é or ö, although if it's a **Wikipedia** link you can just use the unadorned character. (A suggestion to [have these characters supported](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/132431-server-side-markdown-renderer-doesn-t-accept-or-in-links) has been made on [UserVoice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UserVoice#History).)

Comment: TIL parenthetical sections in MSDN links are optional. Mind = blown.

Comment: Of course, the parentheticals *are* needed if you want to link to a page about an earlier release...

Comment: Would approach #4 be the preferred way to do this in comments? It doesn't seem to work for me. Here's <a href="http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.html#setInputPaths(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job, org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path...)">an example</a>.

Comment: @NickChammas when you're commenting, click the help link to the right of the text box, that will show how to do links in comments.

Comment: @Sam - It's not clear from the help how to link to a URL with parentheses in a comment. Approaches 4, 7, and 8 above look like what I want (in-line linking of text to URL with parentheses), but none of them appear to work in comments.

Comment: OK let me try again with this link: `http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.html#setInputPaths(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job, org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path...)` OK... [here we go!](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.html#setInputPaths(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job, org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path...))

Comment: @NickChammas There's a "space" character in that URL. You need to encode it as "%20" thus: [an example](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.html#setInputPaths(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Ahhhhhh, OK! Thank you for helping me track that down.

Comment: I'll try one as well, by escaping parentheses: `[Android link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor%28int%29)` converts to [Android link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor%28int%29)

Answer (score 38):

I ran into the same thing working on an [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) notebook. You can simply use URL encoding for:

- `(` which is **`%28`**, and for
- `)` which is **`%29`**.

Reference: *[HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)* (W3Schools)

Comment: In the Atom Editor for a correct Markdown preview from all Answers, this was the only method that worked.

Comment: This also works for TFS-Web interface where `<>` does not.

Comment: This works for Roam (e.g. in links to Wikipedia)

Answer (score 22):

Use the `<a>` notation instead of the `[ ]` notation.

e.g. `<a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(VS.85).aspx">IHtmlDocument2 reference</a>`

Answer (score 17):

You can do it like this:

```
link to [IHtmlDocument2 reference][1]

   [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(VS.85).aspx
```

For what it's worth, () are parentheses. Braces are {}.

Comment: As long as we're discussing semantics, I've also heard parentheses called "round braces", which I think is a kind-of neat and more generic/accurate term for them.

Comment: Worth mentioning (for future readers) that when this was a problem back in 2008 until 2014, this method wouldn't work in comments.

Comment: [Let’s call the whole thing off](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRrw2hDjnl4&t=25s). *"[...the word bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) is commonly used to refer to a specific form of bracket, which varies from region to region. In* ***most English-speaking countries,*** *an unqualified 'bracket' refers to the round bracket; in the United States, the square bracket".* Also, "***round brackets or parentheses***. *Square brackets or brackets*. *Curly brackets or braces*. *Angle brackets or chevrons*".

Answer (score 16):

FYI, if you're trying to do this in Octopress or Jeckyll, you'll see that some of these methods don't work.

You can use the delimiters inside the parens like this:

```
[My Link](<http://example.com/test(1)>)
```

Which looks like this:

[My Link](http://example.com/test(1))

Comment: Excellent answer. Works for images too.

Comment: Except when there are more parentheses inside like: `[HMS Ark Royal, 1941](<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Ark_Royal_(91)#Final_voyage_and_sinking>)`  which gives:- [HMS Ark Royal, 1941](<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Ark_Royal_(91)#Final_voyage_and_sinking>)  & which can someplaces (reddit) be corrected with an internal backslash for the inner `)` but alas not here:- [HMS Ark Royal, 1941](<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Ark_Royal_(91\)#Final_voyage_and_sinking>)

Answer (score -3):

One workaround is to use a service like [TinyURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyURL) or [Bitly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitly) to shorten the URL.

Comment: URL shorteners are strongly discouraged because there's no indication of where they point.  For example, is http://tinyurl.com/Example a link to example.com, or to goatse?

Comment: They can also break. If the url shortener goes away then so does the URL.