# preview vs post linking difference

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, editor, markdown-preview

> **Vaguely related to:**
>   [Links to URLs containing parentheses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses)

This is likely to do with encoding URLs for safety, but here's a case that works in the preview and the rollover title is "Speakers" yet breaks when posted:

```
[Boston Dev Days][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.carsonified.com/events/boston/(Speakers)
```

The outcome looks like this:
[Boston Dev Days](http://stackoverflow.carsonified.com/events/boston/%28Speakers))

While the preview looks like this:
[Boston Dev Days](http://stackoverflow.carsonified.com/events/boston/)

*If you haven't yet spotted the difference, please mouse over each link above.*

It is proper to put a space between the url and the parenthesis, but the preview accepts the improper format.
I might note this is **a preview bug**.
The preview will lead you to think that the format shown is a correct way of adding a comment/title to a url. It is not.

Also breaks if you use [multiple words][4] yet shows in the preview fine. And lastly, if you make a code block like the one I just made, then use control-L to link a word later on, the url number for `[1]` which should have been the "outcome" line, becomes `[2]` and `[1]` remains assigned as it was, but is mistakenly assigned to the non-linked text in the code block.

Clearly these are minor, but it's worth noting for completeness.

[4]: http://stackoverflow.carsonified.com/events/boston/(multiple words)

Comment: I always give my links names `[Perl::Module]: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Perl::Module`

Comment: Dupe: [Links to URLs containing parentheses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses), additionally, spaces are not valid URL characters

Comment: yeah, when you look at the PREVIEW the (multiple words) are not parsed as part of the URL. You are misled to believe that the format http://host/path(comment) is acceptable. It is not. So the preview is wrong. Simple?

Answer (score 1):

Probably that feature ( or bug ) was introduced around the time Jeff wrote this:

**The Problem With URLs**

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001181.html

Answer (score 1):

The title issues are fixed now (or will be after the next deployment). The URL numbering bug I cannot reproduce; considering that this bug report is almost 1 1/2 years old, this has probably been fixed since then.