# URLs ending with ) are not well parsed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editor

Like in [The Facebook footer bar is an iframe, so why it doesn't it reload with the rest of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562460/facebook-footer-bar-ajax) the link to the wikipedia article could not be set: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Comment: As you noticed, you have to escape the parentheses. A good browser will do that for you...
(this has been reported many times - Brandon illustrated another way of getting the link to work in his edit)

Comment: This is a known issue. You can take a look at these two questions for more details on linking on SO. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18323/preview-vs-post-linking-difference

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially by design; have you read [the markdown help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)?

There are at least 5 different ways to make links

```
http://foo.com
<http://foo.com>
[foo](http://foo.com)
<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>
```

and of course the default toolbar markdown (footer-y) way