# Edit preview bug - preview doesn't match real

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

I was editing an answer that left the url malformed and misparsed. Below is an image that illustrates the problem.

Now, I understand this has [come up before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25706/urls-ending-with-are-not-well-parsed), and has been classified as "by design." However, the fact that the preview and the real message do not match indicates to me there's an unintended problem.

Culprit: An answer on [Why did the Chelyabinsk meteor explode?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/423/can-a-moon-have-have-another-large-body-as-a-satellite-and-are-there-any-example)

---

[image: Freehand circles abound]