# bug report: preview doesn't match "the real thing"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown-preview

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Preview should match the posted view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view)
>   [preview vs post linking difference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18323/preview-vs-post-linking-difference)

In this page:

[How do you force a java swt program to "move itself to the foreground"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315560/how-do-you-force-a-java-swt-program-to-move-itself-to-the-foreground)

in the preview the "footnote" links look pretty

in the real thing they don't

Just so you're aware.
Thanks.

The text in question is (these are links all on a new line, and in the preview they're each on a new line

```
Related:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309023/howto-bring-a-java-window-to-the-front
http://book.javanb.com/swt-the-standard-widget-toolkit/ch11lev1sec4.html
http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg35192.html
[2] http://www.generation-nt.com/us/more-single-instance-apps-how-force-its-window-foregroun-help-27562692.html
[1] http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg35253.html and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=192036
```

Comment: Dupe of **countless** questions, such as most of the ones to the "Related" tab on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a duplicate (sorry dupe voters).

You're not using valid Markdown syntax. See

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

for reference.

Comment: fascinating.
Appears that adding a closing </pre> fixed the problem. Thanks!
I was a bit confused because github's markdown wasn't stingy in that regard.

I suppose you can consider this a "feature request" to be more lenient markdown-wise, then.
Thanks.