# How can I convert a link to a SO-safe link?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, stack-exchange, markdown

I am trying to post this link

[`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan's_off-line_least_common_ancestors_algorithm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan's_off-line_least_common_ancestors_algorithm)

on StackOverflow, and it doesn't get linked because of the `'`.

**How can I convert it into a postable link (w/o using any URL shortners, of course)?**

I remember `(` can be replaced by a `%028`. What is the similar conversion for a `'`?

---

Okay, I realized after posting that it was not getting linked in the JavaScript preview, but it gets linked when it is posted. Still, how can I convert the links to JavaScript preview safe links as mentioned above?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Thanks Ladybug, I think I would have accepted it as the answer, if it were an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use Firefox. It'll automatically encode that pesky apostrophe when you copy the URL out of the address bar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_least_common_ancestors_algorithm
2. Replace the apostrophe with a HTML entity: 
   `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan&apos;s_off-line_least_common_ancestors_algorithm`
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan's_off-line_least_common_ancestors_algorithm
3. Don't worry about it. As you note, it works once you've posted it.

Answer (score 3):

[As of recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60211/auto-escape-url-when-entering-with-hyperlink-button-ctrll/82263#82263), the editor will do that automatically for you when entering a link via the button (or Ctrl-L).

Answer (score -3):

This is a bug. `'` is valid in the path portion of the URL (and so are `(` and `)`).

See RFC 3986:

```
URI           = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
hier-part     = "//" authority path-abempty
              / path-absolute
              / path-rootless
              / path-empty
path-abempty  = *( "/" segment )
segment       = *pchar
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

Comment: True, so far as it goes, but when you're dealing with systems that try to parse URLs out of markup using regular expressions that *probably* were never tested against anything at all unusual, it's a good deal safer to just escape punctuation.

Comment: @Shog What systems are you talking about? This is about stackoverflow code recognizing a valid URL. It does not recognize a valid URL, hence it's a bug. If the problem is dealing with those buggy systems, SO can just escape those characters afterwards...

Comment: [sure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46863/url-not-rendering-on-stackoverflow) [it's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42345/link-refusing-to-show-up) [a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18323/preview-vs-post-linking-difference-closed). But not one that [will be](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40258/bug-report-preview-doesnt-match-the-real-thing) [fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25706/urls-ending-with-are-not-well-parsed). Lazer's question was, "How can I make this link work anyway?" not "Is this a bug".

Comment: @Shog So... this was fixed server-side, but not client-side. Brilliant.