# Link is not recognised as such when put in parentheses

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Links to URLs containing parentheses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses)
>   [URLs ending with ) are not well parsed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25706/urls-ending-with-are-not-well-parsed)
>   [URL inside parenthesis are not automatically hyperlinked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99904/url-inside-parenthesis-are-not-automatically-hyperlinked)

Just found this question here, where this problem occurs:

> [best java Xml parser to manipulate/edit an existing xml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523381/best-java-xml-parser-to-manipulate-edit-an-existing-xml-document)

The problem can be reproduced like this:

> ([best java Xml parser to manipulate/edit an existing xml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523381/best-java-xml-parser-to-manipulate-edit-an-existing-xml-document))

This is a workaround:

> (
>   [best java Xml parser to manipulate/edit an existing xml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523381/best-java-xml-parser-to-manipulate-edit-an-existing-xml-document)
>   )

**UPDATE**: The problem here is really the opening parentheses, which keeps the link from being recognised as such. This works:

> ( [best java Xml parser to manipulate/edit an existing xml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523381/best-java-xml-parser-to-manipulate-edit-an-existing-xml-document))))

But any of these don't:

> {[best java Xml parser to manipulate/edit an existing xml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523381/best-java-xml-parser-to-manipulate-edit-an-existing-xml-document)
>
> [[best java Xml parser to manipulate/edit an existing xml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523381/best-java-xml-parser-to-manipulate-edit-an-existing-xml-document)
>
> ([best java Xml parser to manipulate/edit an existing xml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523381/best-java-xml-parser-to-manipulate-edit-an-existing-xml-document)

**UPDATE**: OK, so the true workaround is this:

> ([best java Xml parser to manipulate/edit an existing xml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523381/best-java-xml-parser-to-manipulate-edit-an-existing-xml-document))
>
> written as (<...>)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Links to URLs containing parentheses](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses), [preview vs post linking difference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18323/preview-vs-post-linking-difference), [URLs ending with ) are not well parsed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25706/urls-ending-with-are-not-well-parsed)

Comment: This one here is really about parentheses *not* being part of the URL... So I think it's another issue... Or maybe a regression introduced by any of the fixes related to those?

Comment: The way I read those answers, it's still [by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25706/urls-ending-with-are-not-well-parsed/25718#25718). Wrapping a URL in parentheses is not how you indicate that it is a URL. There's probably a better dupe, though. I seem to remember reading it more recently.

Comment: OK, well, too bad... :-)

Comment: @Cody, you're right. See the last update. I didn't know about that markup, though...