# URLs with parentheses display incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Links to URLs containing parentheses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses)

The following shows up fine in the Markdown preview but not in an actual answer:

```
[the API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer(javax.xml.transform.Source\))
```

[the API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer(javax.xml.transform.Source))

Comment: You could post a screenshot for people that cannot edit this question to see the source code

Comment: @Downvoter: Not at work, I can't.  But, I don't see the need anyways; I already posted the source in plain text.  Am I misunderstanding you horribly?

Comment: This is why I always encode the parentheses as %28 and %29.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses
(summary: the parser doesn't do nested parens, so either use a syntax that doesn't involve wrapping the URL itself in parentheses, or encode them (Firefox will actually do this for you when you copy the URL out of the address bar... http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer%28javax.xml.transform.Source%29)

Comment: @Shog9: Thanks, I am having terrible luck finding dupes myself lately.  Voting to close.

Comment: tagged [status-completed] because the confusing preview is fixed; the link as posted doesn't work by design (see Jeff's answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preview now supports one level of opened/closed parenthesis. That's still less than the serverside Markdown supports, but covers the usual cases:

- `[foo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(VS.85).aspx)`
- `[bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicorn_(disambiguation))`

This will go live in the next build.

Answer (score 1):

Reopening due to misinformation being presented.

Why are you randomly escaping the last paren and breaking the nesting? This works fine.

```
[the API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer(javax.xml.transform.Source))
```

[the API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer(javax.xml.transform.Source))

You might be freaked out because the PREVIEW doesn't get it right, but the server side does.

Comment: Ah.  After I saw that the preview got it wrong, I never even tried to post it that way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All MSDN URLs seem to use embedded parentheses which break the parser. For example, this markdown:

```
A [foo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(VS.85).aspx) B
```

Yields this result:

A [foo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(VS.85).aspx) B

The Markdown link format should still be able to parse this by looking for `\S+\)` (find the last occurrence of the paren within non-whitespace), right?

Comment: you can omit that parens part though, it is optional on MSDN. try it yourself..

Comment: Interesting; that will help me in the future with MSDN urls specifically. Thanks! The problem still remains for parens in the middle of the URL for any sites that might put them there.