# Would it be possible to fix links containing parentheses in comments?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown, hyperlinks

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses), several workarounds are shown for inserting links containing parentheses (()). However, they don't work for comments, because you cannot insert the extra line break needed for the

```
[SomeLinkText][1]
[1]:http://example.com
```

syntax to work. It just seems like an arbitrary limitation; I know that this prevents one from using Regex to match the URL expressions, but [we know what happens when one uses regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The #2 work-around on that page (urlencoding the parens) works in comments. Firefox will do it for you if you copy the URL directly from the address bar.

Note that [certain sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) actually work better if you just strip the parenthetical portions out before posting anyway...

Comment: For example to link to [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) simply use "`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29`"... note that  this is **not** [ASCII encoding](http://www.asciitable.com/) but [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: Okay -- since MSDN links are so common, maybe they should be detected and the parens should be simply stripped? No idea here.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming your regex hint is supposed to suggest that correctly nested parentheses could be handled. It's certainly true that parens are [legal characters in URLs](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt). But no specification says that parentheses in URLs have to be correctly opened and closed. So this:

```
http://example.com/somewhere)XYZ/42
```

is a perfectly valid URL. But are you seriously suggesting that this comment:

```
For more information, see [this page](http://example.com/somewhere)XYZ/42).
```

should work?

**Edit:** Okay, the usual case (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42305/urls-with-parentheses-display-incorrectly/74074#74074) for examples) will be supported in comments after the next build.

Comment: It's impossible with the current system to get them all to work, but nevertheless I think it would be beneficial to support URLs with matching parens, which are the vast majority of them.