# Comment bug with URLs and square brackets

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown, hyperlinks

Writing URLs in comments that include square brackets like:

```
[text](http://somesite.com/index.php?x[]=y)
```

requires escaping the brackets in order for the link to work properly (otherwise, the square brackets vanish from the link):

```
[text](http://somesite.com/index.php?x\[\]=y)
```

An example of a useful URL containing square brackets:

```
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=php-common&srodzaj=3&dist[]=55
```

Comment: [Example](http://somesite.com/index.php?x[]=6) / `[Example](http://somesite.com/index.php?x[]=6)`

Comment: [Example 2](http://somesite.com/index.php?x\[\]=6) / `[Example 2](http://somesite.com/index.php?x\[\]=6)`

Comment: possibly related (though not duplicate): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63366/would-it-be-possible-to-fix-links-containing-parentheses-in-comments

Answer (score 2):

This will be working after the next build.

See [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88297/url-filter-goes-rogue-on-unicode-characters-in-urls/128824#128824) for details.