# Link button in post editor escapes square brackets in code

Tags: bug, editor, auto-linking

The link button in the post editor incorrectly escapes square brackets in inline code.

To reproduce:

- Write the following MarkDown in the editor

  ```
  text text `function[]` text text
  ```
- Select `` `function[]` ``, press the link button ([image: link button]), and enter some link
- the result will be `` [`function\[\]`][1] `` which renders as `function\[\]`

This comes up very often in [Mathematica-related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematica) when I'm linking to the documentation because the usual way to indicate that a symbol is a function in Mathematica is adding `[]` after it.

This is a minor thing, as it's easy to manually remove the backslashes, but it's somewhat annoying so I thought I'd mention it.

---

*Edit by Mr.Wizard*
It is September 2013 and this still hasn't been fixed.  While "adding `[]` after it" is not presently the custom on Mathematica.SE this is still a bug and still needs to be fixed.

Comment: I avoid this by not including the `[]` :) However, the few times that I have included, it has not been a problem for me because I never use the link button. If you enter your links by hand (like I do) as: ``[`foo[]`](url)``, then it works perfectly fine...

Comment: @yoda I wasn't really asking for a workaround (there are many), just wanted to make sure the problem was registered.  I don't like `[...](...)` style links (too long and distracting when editing), so I use CTRL-L, which is the same as the link button.

Comment: The way I discovered to deal with this annoyance is to change the text to use `&#91;` and `&#93;` for left and right square brackets respectively. The editor *could* do that for us after we submit the link. --- It's unfortunate that @Szabolcs bug has flown under the radar for a half dozen years while all the related bugs have status-completed - See: [Comment bug with URLs and square brackets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92754/282094) **and** [Would it be possible to fix links containing parentheses in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63366/282094) - Perhaps an edit-bump is due.