# Creating a link that comes after a square bracket confuses the editor

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, editor

First, some related bugs:

[Link button in post editor escapes square brackets in code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122340/link-button-in-post-editor-escapes-square-brackets-in-code)

[Please improve the auto-linking to allow square and round brackets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2323/please-improve-the-auto-linking-to-allow-square-and-round-brackets) (status completed apparently?)

[Editor breaks old links when adding new ones with Ctrl+L, if existing link text has square brackets ([])](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270678/editor-breaks-old-links-when-adding-new-ones-with-ctrll-if-existing-link-text) (definitely fixed)

[New "[tag:" syntax interferes with Markdown links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70529/new-tag-syntax-interferes-with-markdown-links) (status by design)

But I think this is new?

If you have this text

```
[select this text
```

and then select *only* `select this text`(not the leading bracket) the editor's "Insert link"  grabs the unhighlighted square bracket inside of the link text escapes it for you:

and It looks like `[ \[select this text][1]` after using the editor's "Insert link" . It also works on the other side, and you end up going from `tricky]` to `[tricky\]]`.

In all cases *I'm not selecting the bracket*.

Can this bug be fixed?