# Editor's "Insert link" gives up if you try to link text after a square bracket on a new line

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, editor

I found this while writing [Creating a link that comes after a square bracket confuses the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375977/creating-a-link-that-comes-after-a-square-bracket-confuses-the-editor).

It looks like the editor's "Insert link" doesn't like trying to link text on a new line where the first character is a square bracket. I'll have to use a screenshot to explain

`[this makes autolinker unhappy`

[image: text above with 'this makes auto-linker unhappy' selected]

results in this highlighting and no link pop up in the editor:

[image: the text above, but with the blank line and trailing space above it also highlighted]

Clicking "Insert link" again works, and captures the selected text *and the empty bracket* as per the previous bug I found.

Comment: Repro'd on the old (current?) editor. The [new (alpha) editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/241919) didn't have this issue.