# Escape square brackets in comment links

Tags: support, comments, markdown

This may be related to this question: [Comment bug with URLs and square brackets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92754/comment-bug-with-urls-and-square-brackets), however it still appears to be an issue for me.

I wanted to leave a comment with a link, so I typed:

```
[Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)
```

Which displayed the following:

```
[Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])](msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)
```

I had to escape the `byte[]` part in a code block:

```
[Convert.ToBase64String(`byte[]`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)
```

And it worked fine. Is this expected behavior? Is there any way I can escape those square brackets inside my link?

Comment: Example of link issue: [Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Escaping using code block works: [Convert.ToBase64String(`byte[]`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx) but looks a bit strange imo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use backslashes to escape the literal brackets:

```
[Convert.ToBase64String(byte\[\])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)
```

This is rendered as:

[Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)

See the demo comment below this answer as well.

Using backslashes is part of the Markdown standard, see [Backslash Escapes](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash):

> Markdown allows you to use backslash escapes to generate literal characters which would otherwise have special meaning in Markdown’s formatting syntax.

Comment: Demo comment: [Convert.ToBase64String(byte\[\])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You'd think as a developer I would have tried a backslash!!