# Square brackets in hyperlinks is broken in comments

Tags: bug, comments, markdown, hyperlinks

On all Stack Exchange websites, using *square brackets* in a hyperlink like in the following Markdown code is correctly translated into HTML in questions and answers, but not in comments:

> [[class.access]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access).

- In questions and answers, we get the expected:

  > [[class.access]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access)
- In comments, we get the unexcepted:

  > [[class.access]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access)

Comment: Related: [Escape square brackets in comment links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225982). The linked post suggests to use `\[` and `\]`, for example., `[\[class.access\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access)` gives [\[class.access\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access).

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the link. But comments and questions & answers should behave the same way.

Comment: Meh, why use square brackets as link text, there is no use in that. Just don't double them up.

Comment: Fair enough! The two post can probably be considered different - the other is asking how to use links where the title contains square brackets the way MarkDown currently works in the comments - while your post suggests that instead of using a workaround this should be considered a bug. Still, I think that the link to the workaround might be useful for users reading your question. (I hope I remember this correctly - IIRC you need to add `\[` and `\]` also for such links in chat, not only comments.)

Comment: @Luuklag The C++ standard should be quoted like that, it is the name of each paragraph (just look at it).

Comment: [[class.access](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access)] Or you just put the extra brackets outside of the hyperlink, easy fix.

Comment: @Martin Yes the workaround is useful that is why I thanked you. I don’t know which way is the best (requiring the escape character or not) but comments and questions & answers should at least behave consistently.

Comment: @Luuklag I am not looking for a workaround, I am looking for consistency in user experience. Comments should behave the same as questions & answers on this matter.

Comment: Well then I think your in for a pain. IMHO comments use the most basic form of Markup, so that would mean that we should make posts consisted with how markup is handled in comments. So having to escape special characters in posts as well.

Comment: @Luuklag In your [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343694/square-brackets-in-hyperlinks-is-broken-in-comments#comment1151171_343694) above, the leftmost square bracket appears as part of the link text. In the preview, and also after [submitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386491) the post, the leftmost square bracket is not a part of the link text. The behavior in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9417021#9417021) seems to be the same as in the comments, as Martin [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1151168) above.