# Does Cyrillic copy/pasted from a Wikipedia definition kill proper display of hyperlinks in comments, but not in posts?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks, languages

I tried to quote Wikipedia [in a comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/52023/what-is-or-are-the-official-english-names-for-the-eventual-space-station-being-b/52061#comment171587_52061):

> For space-word-deficient folks like myself [Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'[b]), also known as the **Functional Cargo Block or FGB** (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)

It shows as expected in a post, but when put in a comment it fails to display properly. While it also includes some **bold text**, removing that doesn't change things.

**Question:** Does Cyrillic prevent proper display of hyperlinks in comments, but not in posts? Is this expected behavior? Is there a work-around?

---

> [image: Does Cyrillic kill proper display of hyperlinks in comments, but not in posts?]

Text was copy/pasted in my Chrome browser (macOS) from the first sentence of Wikipedia's [Zarya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)

> [image: first sentence of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya]

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might wish to check the nesting of [] and () because it's not otherwise obvious what's happened.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. You are right, **that solved it!** This is a non-question, there's nothing wrong with the Cyrillic. Should I delete it or would you like to post a short answer? For space-word-deficient folks like myself [Zarya Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn', also known as the **Functional Cargo Block or FGB** from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ, is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)

Comment: It's courteous of you to offer that I post an answer, but you should perhaps post one yourself, that's quite acceptable here. It's also apparently fine to make innocent errors. (At least I hope it is, I've made enough myself).

Comment: Can the close voter please comment on why this problem is no longer reproducible?

Comment: @Rob I've posted an answer; I removed both square brackets and demonstrate that it solves the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape square brackets in comment links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225982/escape-square-brackets-in-comment-links)

Comment: @SebastianSimon per [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364245/303080) it does offer a way to resolve the behavior I saw but since [Rob's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364247/303080) offers a lot more detail about the use of quotes from Wikipedia and the way they are formatted, I think sending future readers away from that answer might in fact do them a disservice. Since this answer seems valuable and quite helpful to future readers and there's nothing similar there, in this case I am going to say **No**. Instead I'll refine the title to make clearer whats different here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The easiest way to write that so it appears correctly ***and*** can be copied **as-is** into a comment is thusly:

   > `[Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)\[[b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya#cite_note-3)\][), also known as the Functional Cargo Block or FGB (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)\[2\] The FGB provided ...`

   Result:

   > [Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)[[b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya#cite_note-3)][), also known as the Functional Cargo Block or FGB (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)[2] The FGB provided ...

   Notes:

   - I *improved* the Wikipedia version to make it compliant with best HTML practices, multiple links must be separated by at least one character (not a space). So it's not precisely equal to the Wikipedia text, or your copy.
   - Notice how I escaped the additional square brackets using a backslash, that's the key here, as either failing to do so or attempting to use HTML entities fails in comments.
   - The above text has three links, the first and third are identical. The **b** is the second, separate, link.
2. The *better* way to write that ***but*** it appears correctly ***only*** in the post, and can **not** be copied **as-is** into a comment is thusly:

   > `[Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)<sup>[[b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya#cite_note-3)]</sup>[), also known as the Functional Cargo Block or FGB (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)<sup>[2]</sup> The FGB provided ...`

   Result:

   > [Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)<sup>[[b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya#cite_note-3)]</sup>[), also known as the Functional Cargo Block or FGB (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)<sup>[2]</sup> The FGB provided ...

   Notice the correct superscripting of the square brackets and the **b** link, without making the square brackets themselves part of the link. Such beauty becomes ugliness within a comment's Markdown limitations.

---

Reference Sandbox Test: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364246/282094

Original Wikipedia Text: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya

> "Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'<sup>[b]</sup>), also known as the Functional Cargo Block or FGB (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched.<sup>[2]</sup> The FGB provided electrical power, storage, propulsion, and guidance to the ISS during the initial stage of assembly. With the launch and assembly in orbit of other modules with more specialized functionality, Zarya is now<sup>[when?]</sup> primarily used for storage, both inside the pressurized section and in the externally mounted fuel tanks."

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

[Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364243/does-cyrillic-kill-proper-display-of-hyperlinks-in-comments-but-not-in-posts/364245#comment1215568_364243) has been [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364243/does-cyrillic-kill-proper-display-of-hyperlinks-in-comments-but-not-in-posts/364245#comment1215573_364243) thanks to A Rogue Ant. and to Rob. It's the embedded square brackets in the quote, *and totally unrelated to Cyrillic.*

`For space-word-deficient folks like myself [Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'[b]), also known as the **Functional Cargo Block or FGB** (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)`

fails but simply removing the "[b]" square brackets inside works.

`For space-word-deficient folks like myself [Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'), also known as the **Functional Cargo Block or FGB** (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)`

Both are posted as a comments under this answer and removing the "[b]" works nicely!

Comment: For space-word-deficient folks like myself [Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'), also known as the **Functional Cargo Block or FGB** (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)

Comment: ORIGINAL (has the "[b]" square brackets): For space-word-deficient folks like myself [Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'[b]), also known as the **Functional Cargo Block or FGB** (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)

Comment: Check out my answer, which produces this style of comment text: [Zarya (Russian: Заря́, lit. 'Dawn'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)\[[b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya#cite_note-3)\][), also known as the Functional Cargo Block or FGB (from the Russian: "Функционально-грузовой блок", lit. 'Funktsionalno-gruzovoy blok' or ФГБ), is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)\[2\] The FGB provided ...

Comment: You don’t need to remove the `[b]`. Simply escape the square brackets with a backslash, i.e. `\[b\]`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon yes that is the simplest and most straightforward solution. I don't think that particularly simple solution is covered in the other answer or not; if not please feel free to edit my answer and add it in, or post it as a new answer. *Thanks!*