# Markdown for links in comments sometimes breaks with angle brackets and nested square brackets

Tags: bug, comments, markdown, hyperlinks

The following markdown:

```
[[example].com](https://www.example.com) (<https://www.example.com/abc>)
```

Produces this in a post:

[[example].com](https://www.example.com) (https://www.example.com/abc)

But this in a comment:

[[example].com]([example.com](https://www.example.com)) (<[example.com/abc>](https://www.example.com/abc%3E))

Comment: [[example].com](https://www.example.com) (<https://www.example.com/abc>)

Comment: Reference image of what I see in case this is browser-dependent or something: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVogk.png

Comment: Related: *[Escape square brackets in comment links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225982/escape-square-brackets-in-comment-links)*. See also [the \[linked\] questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/225982). [A query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=comments+escape+brackets).