# Comments containing a link with a Closing Parenthesis are broken

Tags: support, bug, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would it be possible to fix links containing parentheses in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63366/would-it-be-possible-to-fix-links-containing-parentheses-in-comments)

In [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/455/what-if-our-sun-were-located-in-the-middle-of-a-globular-cluster/458#458), there is a comment with a link that ends with a Closing Parenthesis `)`.

I successfully reproduced it in the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/95802#95802) but, as you see here (it looks like it's not working in questions too), the Closing Parenthesis is not added at the end of the link when you follow it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightfall_(Asimov_short_story)

While it works [this way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightfall_%28Asimov_short_story%29) and [this way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightfall_(Asimov_short_story)), it's hard to fix this in comments because of the editing rules.