# URL ending in parenthesis regression or new problem?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL 'encoding' bug with urls containing multiple parens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110423/url-encoding-bug-with-urls-containing-multiple-parens)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log(v=vs.110)

the final parenthesis is not included in the href on a naked URL

If you [put it in a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log%28v=vs.110%29), it gets escaped

Not sure if it falls into this fix or not: [URLs with parentheses display incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42305/urls-with-parentheses-display-incorrectly) - if it does (as opposed to parentheses fully within the URL), perhaps it somehow got broken again.