# Tag wiki link problem with ')'

Tags: support, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Links to URLs containing parentheses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses)

The tag wiki:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?sort=info&tagnames=java

Has problems dealing with the link

```
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)
```

The last parenthesis is missing when the link is created.

Comment: Arrgh, that title just bothers me. I can't stand to see an unmatched parenthesis like that.

Comment: ( ( ( ( ( ( ( (

Comment: Like what?  like this? `)`  ??? :) :)   what about: `}}` or `(}`

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the parentheses or use a different syntax for linking, [same as elsewhere on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses). I've fixed it for you.