# How to put direct links to URL containing /*/ in answers or chat?

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

Let's say you have this URL :

```
http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html
```

The only solution I found to include it in an answer was to use an URL shortener. The `/*/` (probably half of it, really) seems to confuse the markdown parser.

Note that you can include the link in HTML ([fiddle here](http://jsbin.com/inepiw/1)) but that this HTML gets broken too when you include it in a SO answer.

Is there a solution which doesn't involve using a third party and masking the URL to SO ? Is that a bug ?

Comment: [Using proper markdown works...kind of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99586/136489). For some reason it keeps redirecting me to the current site, even though the link is shown as absolute. But that smells like a bug in Firefox. It looks like both, the colon, the asterisk and the double-slash seem to break something...but that doesn't look like a problem of SE.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work to me : it breaks it into two links.

Comment: That's why I said "using ***proper*** markdown". Dumping a link into the post and expecting it to become a link is not "using proper markdown".

Comment: Can you give an example of proper markdown working for this link ? I tried (for example using `[text](url)`) and couldn't find one.

Comment: See the link the the sandbox-post I provided.

Comment: None of the link goes to the right page (the one you get if you past the URL from my question here to the url input of your browser).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said. But that seems to be a browser-problem, the links in the post are correct as far as I can see it.

Comment: I don't think it's a browser problem as you can easily include the link in HTML outside of SO (see link to fiddle in my question here).

Comment: Yeah, that's odd. But I can't see a difference between the two links (HTML-wise).

Comment: [I tried my own fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E4kq9/). The links there work, *even that one C&P from the Sandbox post*. So there is something fishy going on, but I don't think it is Stack Exchange, or at least not entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you explicitly say "this is a link" (by using the `[foo](http://bar)` syntax, or by, as you tried, explicitly inserting HTML), this works fine now. Simply pasting the URL into the text by itself will *not* work correctly; auto-recognition of linkable URLs is [intentionally limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110434/115866) and will stop on the asterisk.

Comment: For some weird reason, [this SmokeDetector message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18088146#18088146) not only included a link to the post, but also to the spam (hover over the http://spamlink.com part). Is this a bug, or by design? It appears have *something* to do with recent changes, as [this message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18087863#18087863) is fine.

Comment: That has *nothing* to do with recent changes. Those messages are not identical (one has `http://`, one doesn't). Also note that it's only broken in the transcript (which is traditionally pretty broken when it comes to auto-linking); it works fine in the live chat.