# How can I diminish the link, writing few words?

Tags: support, edits, markdown, hyperlinks

When I copy a link and paste it, it can be so long. I need to shorten it. How can I do that?

How can I make a link from one word? For example, the word **here**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Links to URLs containing parentheses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13509/282094), covers additional examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the word you want to link in square brackets and the actual link in parentheses. Like this:

```
[Here](https://www.google.com) is a link.
```

This is the result of the above code:

[Here](https://www.google.com) is a link.