# Problem posting links

Tags: support, hyperlinks, anchor

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Links to URLs containing parentheses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses)
>   [Please improve the auto-linking to allow square and round brackets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2323/please-improve-the-auto-linking-to-allow-square-and-round-brackets)

I tried posting the following link in a post on Stack Overflow.
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToView(int)

However when clicking on the link, the browser cut off the last part of the url "(int)", so the link did not go to the correct anchor in the page.  This happened in Google Chrome, I have not tried any other browsers yet.  Is this a bug with Stack Overflow?  Is there a way around it?

Comment: @Jon that post isn't `[status-completed]`; [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2323/please-improve-the-auto-linking-to-allow-square-and-round-brackets/2346#2346) is

Answer (score 3):

Use proper percent-encoding [for reserved characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters):

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToView%28int%29

(However, though reserved, a non-encoded bracket *could* be part of an URL. In this example, it should be encoded though, and meanwhile also fixes the problem with the clickable link...)

It's actually easier to just use [Markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)'s `< ..>`, just like shown in the "How to Format" box to the right when composing a post:

[image]

Hence:

```
<http://java.sun.com/[..]/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToView(int)>
```

would yield:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToView(int)

But: that's still ugly, and to make proper Markdown formatting work in the preview as well<sup>†</sup>, you need the percent-encoded URL anyway:

```
[convertColumnIndexToView(int)](http://[..]#convertColumnIndexToView%28int%29)
```

yielding:

[convertColumnIndexToView(int)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToView%28int%29)

Much better!

<sup>†</sup> Even though the preview doesn't like trailing parentheses when using the `[name](url)` or `[name][id]` syntax, the end result for both [is actually fine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses/13509#13509).